# Cannot access firebase database (despite making read rule true)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am building an app using React-Native and Firebase.

Code that worked in another app (to pull from firebase) failed to work this time. So, I modified it to be simpler - a one time data call, and I get the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: permission_denied at /userList: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

Even if I make the rules 'true' (open to anyone) I still get the same error. Elsewhere in the same app, I have other read/write functions that work.

Here are my current Rules and Database structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "public": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    },
    "feedback": {
       "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    },
    "userList": {
     "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
   }
  }
}
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8U9R.png)

Here is my action creator that makes the call:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export const NAMES_FETCH = 'names_fetch'
export const namesFetch = () => {

  return (dispatch) => {
      firebase.database().ref(`/userList`).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var names = snapshot.val();
        console.log('FIREBASE PRINT', names)
      });

    };
  };
```

I've tried everything, and am at my wits end. Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the very same code works if I change the ref to 'users' instead of 'userList'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase checks read permission when you attach a listener. If you have read permission to the location, the read or query is allowed. If you don't have read permission on the location, the read or query is rejected.

In your case the read gets rejected, because no one has read permission to `/userList`.

So: to query a location you must have read permission on that location. And once you have read permission on a location, you can also read all data under that location ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade). This means that queries cannot be used to filter data that you don't have access to, which the Firebase documentation calls [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

Also see some of the many other [questions about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters), many of which contain workarounds for this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!  Just one follow-up: why does no one have read permission to /userList?  I thought thats what my rules allowed under userList.   The easiest fix would be to give all read permission, but from your answer I'm guessing this breaks the rules are not filters guideline???  Thanks

Comment: I see my mistake. Thank you for your answer!